Rotational intertia of a rigid body consisting of three spheres connected by rods of negligible weight
I have a problem to solve which consists of the following:
Three spheres of radius a and mass m are connected by 3 rods of length l and negligible mass. The angle between each rod is 120°. (See the diagram below)

In my assignment, I have to solve for the rotational inertia of the entire rigid body around the centre (where all the sticks connect).
My idea was that I could calculate each sphere's rotational inertia around its own centre of mass and then use the parallel axis theorem.
Each sphere's rotational intertia around its own centre of mass is given by (2/5)ma^2. Using the parallel axis theorem, sphere 1 has a rotational inertia of (2/5)ma^2 + ml^2 around the centre. Sphere 2 and 3 both have a rotational intertia of (2/5)ma^2 + m((√3/2)l)^2 around the centre.
Adding these up, I get the body's rotational inertia around the centre as (37/10)m(a^2 + l^2). Would this be correct? It seems like a weird answer to me.

All of the spheres have 2/5ma^2 + ml^2; wrong your part of the square root of 3. It could be  2/5ma^2 + m(a+l)^2, depending on how you interpret the situation

I think you have misunderstood the direction of the axis of rotation. The spheres are almost certainly meant to be rotating in the plane of the paper, with the axis of rotation at right angle to the paper (although the question does not spell this out).

You are making a mistake in your understanding of rotational inertia. All that determines the effect of some mass on the rotational inertia is its distance from the axis of rotation. Since the axis of rotation goes through the center of the object, you can just factor in the contribution of each mass on the rotational inertia and sum them up. The distance of each mass from the rotational axis is l+a, the sum of the length of the rod and the radius of the mass (assuming that the rods attach to the surface of the masses rather than their centers). Using the equation I = ΣMR^2, we get I = 3m(l+a)^2.
Remember that rotational inertia is analogous to mass in a rotational frame, acting as resistance to rotational motion. This is why increasing the length of a cylinder has no effect on the rotational inertia if the axis of rotation passes through the center of its cross-sectional face - extension along that axis does not contribute to the distance a particle must be rotated from, and as a result the average torque that must be applied to the system, which in itself is analogous to force. Parallel axis theorem is practically what I did here, adding the individual moments of inertia of each rod+mass object. By the way it seems, you did your moment inertia through an arbitrary axis that goes through one of the masses.
If you want further information about rotational inertia, I suggest this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ic_wFYu8xVs
